# Showing "Please Wait" Dialog in ConnectionRequest

Tags: codenameone

please how do i best implement "please wait" dialog while making Network Connection usingConnectionRequest request = new ConnectionRequest();i tried this bellow but is having issueDialog req_dialog = new Dialog("please wait");request.setShowOnInit(req_dialog);request.setDisposeOnCompletion(req_dialog);

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using:

```
dlg.showModless();
addToQueueAndWait(con);
dlg.dispose();
```